# Is there a way to (manage) add milliseconds ( to now() ) in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I want to add milliseconds to delay jobs in laravel queue. We can add seconds like:

```
SaveJob::dispatch($data)->delay( now()->addSeconds(1) );
```

But I need to add milliseconds. I didn't come across such a method in the Carbon library. But to get some ideas I wanted to ask anyway.

Comment: From [this GitHub page](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/issues/232), assigning milliseconds does not appear to be supported.  But, you can read milliseconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pratical alternative: [usleep - Delay execution in microseconds](https://php.net/manual/en/function.usleep.php)

To sleep for two miliseconds:

```
usleep( 2 * 1000 );
```

So in your case, can you please try:

```
SaveJob::dispatch($data)->delay( now()->usleep( 2 * 1000 ) );
```

or

```
SaveJob::dispatch($data)->delay( usleep( 2 * 1000 ) );
```

Comment: There is no such method like usleep within the library class. You can't use this like that. Besides usleep and sleep are commands that directly delaying the current execution. Even if this would work it wouldn't work asynchronous.

Comment: My bad, didn't thought of the task and async. As you mentioned, it might not work async for given task. It's hard to say for little source code. But thanks for noting that. Looking for other solutions.